# Ruby: How to pass a variable from server to index?

Tags: ruby, post, get, sinatra, erb

```
something = "0"

get "/" do
   erb :index, :locals => something
end
```

When I do this and go to localhost, it says undefined method `keys' for "0":String. I am using sinatra. How do I pass a variable from server to index?

Comment: params are a hash so it would need to be `something = {some_param: "0"}` then you could access it as `some_param` in the view through `locals`.

Answer (score 0):

You're half way there, you just need to make `something` an object.

```
get "/" do
   erb :index, :locals => {:something => 0}
end
```

and then just use it in the your index:

```
Something: <%= something %>
```